# How to find and check if user is member in one action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

```
class Api::V1::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    if User.find_by(member_id: params[:user][:member_id])
      self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
      sign_in(resource_name, resource)
      resource.reset_authentication_token!
      resource.save!
    else
      error :not_found
    end
  end
end
```

How to change create action to be sure than only users with role: '`member`' can sign in. And for example admins (`user.role => :admin`) got `error => :unauthorized`

Comment: Are you using a gem for roles? If so which one? If not, do you have a method that returns whether or not a user has a particular role?

Comment: I am using CanCan. I have method => ``User.last.role == :member``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lazy verison would be to raise an exception when found user is not member, but good design should not use exceptions to handle normal cases.

Maybe like this?

```
user = User.find_by(member_id: params[:user][:member_id])
return error :unauthorized unless user.role == :member

if user
  ...
else
  ...
end
```